# Paused on exception TypeError: Cannot read property ' label' of null - Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs

Usando el **autocomplete** de **material-ui**, con `useEffect` traigo los datos desde la API y muestra la lista de  los nombres de los estados ,si selecciono un y doy click en el boton guardar, el registro se guarda correctamente,  pero si escojo un valor y limpio el **autocomplete** aparece el siguiente error:

> Paused on exception  TypeError: Cannot read property ' label' of null

¿Como puedo corregir este error?

```
import React, { useState,useEffect}  from 'react';
import  axios  from 'axios';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete'

function AgregarDireccion(props) {

   const [direccion, setDireccion] = useState({ label: '',  ciudad: '', codigo_postal:0 }) 

   const[lista, setLista]=useState({Datos:[]});

    useEffect(()=>{
        const getList=async()=>{
            const response =await axios.get(urlciudad);
           setLista(response.data);
         }
        getList();
    },[]);


          const defaultProps={
            options:location.Estados,
            getOptionLabel: option =>  option.estado ,
          };

          function GuardarDireccion(event) { 
            setDireccion({...direccion, [event.target.name]: event.target.value})
          }

          function handleSubmit(event) { 
            event.preventDefault();  
            async function agregarDireccion() {
                     await axios.post(url, direccion); 
                }
                agregarDireccion();
            }

      return ( 
        <div > 
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Autocomplete
                style={{ width: 300 }}
                {...defaultProps}
                id="city"
                autoComplete                   
                onChange={(event, newVal)=>GuardarDireccion({target:{name:"label",value: newVal.label }}
                  )}
                renderInput={params => (
                  <TextField {...params}   label="Estado"  margin="normal" variant="outlined" />
                )}
    />
                    <TextField
                    name="ciudad"
                    label="Ciudad"
                    value={direccion.ciudad}
                    onChange={GuardarDireccion}
                    margin="normal"
                    />
                <TextField
                    name="codigo_postal"
                    label="Codigo postal"
                    value={direccion.codigo_postal}
                    onChange={GuardarDireccion}
                    margin="normal"
                />
            <Button
                variant="contained"
                type="submit">
                      Guardar
            </Button>
        </form>
        </div>
    );
    }
```

Comment: Deberías [edit] la pregunta y añadir el componente entero, porque con esos fragmentos es complicado adivinar qué pasa... aparte de que newVal será null

Comment: @PabloLozano ese es el problema que al limpiar el autocomplete o si selecciono un estado y lo borro aparece el error  Cannot read property ' label' of null

Comment: Creo que ese Autocomplete necesita cerrar "/>" y el "onTagsChange" no tendría que ser "this.onTagsChange"?. Concuerdo que necesitamos el componente entero y, si es posible, una captura de lo que le muestra en consola.

Comment: @MoisésHuamánC. estoy usando componentes funcionales donde no se utiliza el this

Comment: Sigo sin entender el problema: newVal puede ser null...  ¿si lo compruebas antes no solucionas el error?

Comment: Comprobandolo de que forma o en donde?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al intentar acceder a una propiedad de un objeto nulo, es cuando te muestra ese error..
Dicho esto, para poderlo corregir, una forma que se me ocurre, es la siguiente:

Cambia:

```
onChange={(event, newVal)=>GuardarDireccion({target:{name:"label",value: newVal.label }}
```

Por:

```
onChange={(event, newVal)=>GuardarDireccion({target:{name:"label",value: dameLabel(newVal) }}

function dameLabel(newVal) {
  if (newVal != null && newVal != undefined) {
    return newVal.label;
  }

  return '';
}
```

De esta forma, el operador "?" interpretará si puedes acceder a la propiedad label o no, si puedes acceder, te devolverá el valor de label, de lo contrario, asignará un valor undefined a "value".

Espero te haya ayudado, un saludo!

Comment: Me aparece el siguiente error Support for the experimental syntax 'optionalChaining' isn't currently enabled con  newVal?.label

Comment: Vale, no es soportado por el navegador: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining
Modifico la respuesta, ahora te aviso

Comment: Ya está modificado @senseilex

Comment: Disculpa estoy copiando exactamente como lo puso en la respuesta, pero en esta parte value: dameLabel(newVal), dice que dameLabel no esta definido

Comment: Has creado la función con la verificación?

Comment: Si aunque pude haberme equivocado en donde ponerla, como la puso abajo del onchange yo asi la puse

Comment: Realmente quise poner una separación, pero igual lo metió dentro del mismo código, debí separalo con un texto o algo, para la siguiente lo mejoro  :)

Comment: No se porque guarda el valor como undefined :(

Comment: Pues si no me equivoco, acabas de limpiar el autocomplete, por lo que el nuevo valor será null/undefined. Quizás lo ideal sería que fuera espacio en blanco, pero... Se ve que no lo hace automático, tendrás que hacerlo en la función y hacer un return ''; si viene sin valor